# White Space in Path is not being ignored in .sh file

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I've searched through multiple questions / responses but didn't find one that worked out for me.

I'm on Windows and I'm trying to run an application through Git Bash:

```
$ ./bin/program.sh config/program.properties
```

And the error I get is:

```
C:/bin/program.sh: line 127: C:\Program: No such file or directory
```

I've narrowed the problem to be an earlier section in the .sh

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA="java"
else
  JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
```

And well, line 127 has:

```
exec $JAVA ...
```

There's more to the line but the problem is in the JAVA_HOME part. My JAVA_HOME is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java
```

I've tried multitudes of different ways to replace the JAVA to beat the white space

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_111\\bin\\java"
"C:\\Program/ Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_111\\bin\\java"
"C:/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java"
C:/"Program Files"/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java
'C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java'
```

There are probably more combinations but I've forgotten. Is this a problem with Git Bash? Or is this something about .sh files that I'm unaware of? Or do white space delimiters do not work when stored in $JAVA? Or is this a completely different problem?

**UPDATE**

Wrapping `$JAVA` in quotes: `"$JAVA"` fixes it.

Comment: wrap them in single quote. for example `'C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java'`

Comment: @0.sh I have tried that as well, I still get `C:/bin/program.sh: line 127: C:\Program: No such file or directory` Will update post to reflect it.

Comment: This `[ -z "$JAVA_HOME"]` will yield an error.

Comment: Did you try exec "$JAVA" ... ?

Comment: @andlrc why will it yield an error? I do have a $JAVA_HOME set in my git-bash so it isn't empty and will set $JAVA to the JAVA_HOME in the .sh. @BorisT Omg it worked! Thank you so much, except now I have an `Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Microsoft`

Comment: @m1771vw there should be a space between "$JAVA_HOME" and the second close `]` .

Comment: @m1771vw can you show us the code in program.sh

Comment: @m1771vw If you need help with another error, you should post a new question. Feel free to link to this one from your new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `bash` is replacing `$JAVA` with its value before executing the `exec` command. This means that

```
exec $JAVA ...
```

becomes

```
exec C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java
```

`exec` sees the arguments only after this replacement occurs. The space in `Program Files` makes it look like this is two separate arguments for `exec`. The first is `C:\Program` and the second is `Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java`.

To solve the problem, you need to either move your Java installation to a directory without a space in the path, or you need to quote the parameter sent to `exec`:

```
exec "$JAVA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the $JAVA in the exec statement and it will look past the white space

```
exec "$JAVA" ...
```

Comment: "it will look past the white space" This isn't exactly correct. With the quotes, the whitespace becomes part of the single argument string rather than being an argument separator